# Visual Studio incorrectly uses information from .rc-file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dialog, resources

I have added 3 static texts to main waindow using the **Visual Studio 2012** resource editor:

[image]

Each static is at the same distance from each other. It is equal to **8**

Here is the code from .rc-file:

```
LTEXT           "Example",IDC_STATIC_1,25,30,35,8
LTEXT           "Example",IDC_STATIC_2,25,38,35,8
LTEXT           "Example",IDC_STATIC_3,25,47,35,8
```

But if you enlarge the image, you can see here that the distances between the statics are different:

[image]

But if to create these statics using `CreateWindowEx()` function, then all distances are the same.

**Question**: why does the **Visual Studio** incorrectly uses controls position information from .rc-file?

Comment: This is neither incorrect nor Visual Studio. It's an artifact of how DLUs get translated into device pixel coordinates.

Comment: 38-30=8, 47-39=9

Comment: @SimonMourier maybe 47-38=9?

Comment: @nevilad - :-) yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. You need to look at the documentation for `MapDialogRect()` and `GetDialogBaseUnits()`.

Dialog units are not pixels. They are their own thing.

When you create a dialog, it scales the dialog using the font for the dialog. If not specified, or it's specified to use the system font, then the dialog will be scaled to that size.

If the font size of a dialog is bigger, then the dialog will be bigger when created, as well as all its elements.